# CM_Request_Device_Eject fails with PNP_VetoIllegalDeviceRequest

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried the code below. It requests ejection when the device name contains "San", because I have plugged in a SanDisk USB drive. However it fails, and the reason seems to be `PNP_VetoIllegalDeviceRequest`. I looked up the reason, and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfg/ne-cfg-pnp_veto_type) says it is

> The device does not support the specified operation.

But I can manually eject the SanDisk using Windows' menu, so the reason seems absurd. Did I call the function correctly? Do I need to call something else before calling `CM_Request_Device_Eject`?

The output was

```
....
SanDisk Ultra USB Device
Removing Sandisk
rejected.
type:8
name:USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Ultra&Rev_1.00\....
```

The code was (the value of `Devinst` was `3`)

```
    if (wcsstr(buffer, L"San") != 0)
    {
        wcout << "Removing Sandisk" << endl;
        PNP_VETO_TYPE vType;
        WCHAR vName[MAX_PATH];
        result = CM_Request_Device_Eject(Devinst, &vType, vName, MAX_PATH, NULL);

        if (result == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << "ejected" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            wcout << "rejected." << endl;
            wcout << "type:"<< vType << endl;
            wcout << "name:" << vName << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching the web, I have found this page: https://www.winvistatips.com/threads/removal-of-usb-disk.179677/

The questioner had the exact same error, and there was a reply that said that he needs to call that function to the parent node, not the USB disk node. So, I modified the code like below, and it worked.

```
        DEVINST parent;
        CM_Get_Parent(&parent, Devinst, NULL);

        PNP_VETO_TYPE vType;
        WCHAR vName[MAX_PATH];
        result = CM_Request_Device_Eject(parent, &vType, vName, MAX_PATH, NULL);
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.